# What book or website should i refer for stm32f0 development from scratch (Ihave worked on AVR microcontrollers )

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, arm, stm32

What book or website should I refer to for STM32F0 development from scratch (I have worked on AVR microcontrollers)? I am searching on net for good resources but unable to do either they are very complex or the model doesn't match with my board ..please suggest some references

Comment: When you say 'from scratch' do you mean you don't want to use the ST-provided standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the manufacturer website: ST.com

You should find Application Notes about the STM32F0 that contain sample code and sample schematics as well.

Then of course you have the *Family Reference Manual*, also available from the ST website that explains all the functionality of the F0.

Then you have the part datasheet, that goes more into details on specific things of the particular device of the F0 family that you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

It is harder to find third-party information about the newer F0 processor. It does have a lot in common with the other STM32 Cortex parts though. Interestingly the peripherals are more similar to the F2/4 than to the comparably sized but older F1.

https://github.com/szczys/stm32f0-discovery-basic-template is a simple project template that will at least get you compiling some C code. Notably lacking is a 'debug' command.